# Tufte `fullwidth + align` without starting new paragraph

Tags: math-mode, tufte, vertical-spacing, fullwidth

How can I achieve a full-width math environment in a Tufte-style document which is vertically spaced correctly, in the sense shown?

Consider the screenshot below. Notice how the vertical spacing on the ‘Textwidth’ `align*` environments respects whether it is mid-paragraph or at the start of one. I want to achieve this behaviour (or just get rid of the new-paragraph vertical skip) with a full-width `align*`, but it seems the `fullwidth` environment contains its own separate paragraph. Can this be corrected?

[image]

```
\documentclass{caesar_book}

\begin{document}

Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
\begin{align*}
    \text{(Textwidth, same paragraph) } 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5
\end{align*}
Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.

\begin{align*}
    \text{(Textwidth, new paragraph) } 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5
\end{align*}
Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
\begin{fullwidth}
    \begin{align*}
        \text{(Fullwidth, same paragraph) } 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10
    \end{align*}
\end{fullwidth}
Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.

\begin{fullwidth}
    \begin{align*}
        \text{(Fullwidth, new paragraph) } 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10
    \end{align*}
\end{fullwidth}
Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.

\end{document}
```

Comment: `fullwidth` is just the `adjustwidth` from `changepage` which in turn is a `list` constuction. Try wrapping `align` in `\begin{list}{}{} ... \end{list}` and you'll get the same result. I don't know if there is a good solution to this. If this is only for wrapping `align`, then I'd make a new env (`fullwidthalign`) and then backtrack the spacing there.

Comment: @daleif Good idea. Any idea why `\begin{fullwidth} \vspace{-\parskip} \begin{align} …` doesn’t do the trick? I hacky solution would be to hardcode an eyeballed length, but I’d like to fix this nicely.

Comment: Try `\vskip-\baselineskip`

Answer (score 1):

To eliminate the extra vertical space in both uses of `fullwidth`, it is necessary to define a new environment --similar to  `fullwidth`-- to be be used when  `align*` is included.

Of course, if you want to simulate the behavior when `fullwidth` is not used, use it only the first time (same paragraph).

[image: c]

```
\documentclass{caesar_book}

\newenvironment{fullwidthx} % added<<<<<<<<<<<<
{\ifthenelse{\boolean{@twoside}}%
    {\begin{adjustwidth*}{}{-\overhang}\vskip-\baselineskip}% <<<<<<<<<
        {\begin{adjustwidth}{}{-\overhang}\vskip-\baselineskip}% <<<<<<<<<<
        }%
        {\ifthenelse{\boolean{@twoside}}%
            {\end{adjustwidth*}}%
        {\end{adjustwidth}}%
}

\begin{document}
    
    Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
    \begin{align*}
        \text{(Textwidth, same paragraph) } 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5
    \end{align*}
    Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
    
    \begin{align*}
        \text{(Textwidth, new paragraph) } 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5
    \end{align*}
    Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
    \begin{fullwidthx} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \begin{align*}
            \text{(Fullwidthx, same paragraph) } 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10
        \end{align*}
    \end{fullwidthx}
    Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
    
    \begin{fullwidthx} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \begin{align*}
            \text{(Fullwidthx, new paragraph) } 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10
        \end{align*}
    \end{fullwidthx}
    Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. The `\vspace-\baselineskip` command is the most helpful point. Since, in practice, I would never start a paragraph with a fullwidth align, it’s appropriate for me to define a `fullwidthalign` environment which is permanently `-\baselineskip`ed. So even though this doesn’t strictly solve the question, I’ll mark this as accepted.